# Aligning two objects to create a fit score

Tags: python, measurement

I am currently in the process of devising an optimal strategy to employ a Python script that will facilitate the alignment of two distinct objects. The alignment is based on a point of origin located on the Z-axis, which will subsequently enable a scoring range from 0 to 100.

The strategy involves the utilization of 50 points derived from both surfaces to ascertain the fitting score. We are in the process of establishing specific regions within both objects that will be aligned and matched. Following this, we will employ a deviation calculation to determine the disparity between the x, y, and z coordinates.

However, it has been brought to my attention that the Euclidean distance may not be a feasible solution in this context, as its application is not typically extended to three-dimensional spaces. This raises the question of what alternative methods could be employed to achieve the desired outcome. I am open to suggestions and further discussion on this matter.

Comment: My current understanding is that Euclidean principles apply in 3D. For clarification, you have 50 indexed points in object A and you would like to grade their deviation from a near-matching set of indexed points in object B? Should you just subtract the positions from one another?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Blender?

Comment: I am using blender to test this out.

Comment: Hello Tim .. welcome to BSE. It does look as if your central question is mathematical / algorithmic. The use of Blender to visualize results is secondary? (if the visualization was your **primary** problem, your post would be more on-topic, here.) Also, at first sight, it's a hard problem, mathematically, maybe less so, with closer definition.. How many degrees of freedom are you allowing in your alignment? Translation / Rotation / Scale ? By your reference to Z, do you mean translation only, on the Z axis? (That might sneak in.)

Comment: At the moment, this question verges on off-topic here and is vulnerable to closure. It might be better posed, say, on Mathematics SE, abstractly, with a very clear statement of constraints. If you want to ask it here, please edit to include a an illustration of your practical, visual, end-purpose,  acceptable error, and  possible routes via mechanisms in the application, to match your question more closely to what we can answer here on Blender SE.

Comment: You should look into CloudCompare which has alignment features (it's open source)